# see firefox when executing robot test in docker

Tags: selenium, docker, firefox, robotframework

I'm using robotframework with selenium and firefox.
I'm running test in a docker.
But for debugging purpose I want to see sometimes what's happen on the UI.

So is there a way to get the UI of firefox launch when test are running in docker.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use VNC to see what is actually happening over docker. It's like remote access where you can see everything on docker image

Download VNC viewer :

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/

Some tutorial :

[Click Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=vnc%20viewer%20docker&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIN822IN822&sxsrf=ACYBGNTEa0w-yhy6QZ0kY2XFsLBpLMJ4YA:1570625700837&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqteTXnI_lAhX7IbcAHfsTDaQQ_AUIEigB&biw=1280&bih=881)

Article

https://medium.com/@shivam.somani09/running-automated-test-cases-on-vnc-viewer-using-docker-16656c3d1d87

OR if you don't want VNC

You can take screenshot if you just want an image on a particular place.
You can also use `driver.getPageSource();` to get the HTML code